# Is it possible to add the same instance of a Windows Forms control to multiple containers?

Tags: c#, winforms

## What I am trying to accomplish:

I have a wizard with multiple pages. On each page, I need to have a ToolStripDropDownButton, each of which has the exact same functionality and UI. The entire wizard and all pages are created before any of them are displayed. The ToolStripDropDownButton is displayed within the bounds of the page. When the user changes the value of the ToolStripDropDownButton on one page, it should be updated on the others.

## The alternative solution I am trying to avoid:

Having a separate instance of the control on each page which subscribes to an event fired when any of the the other controls' value is changed. There is nothing wrong with this solution beyond the complication of it.

## What I have tried:

I created the ToolStripDropDownButton as a static member of the wizard page class, instantiating it at the first request and adding the same object to each page as it is created. This results in the ToolStripDropDownButton appearing on no page (presumably because I have added it to multiple controls and Winforms doesn't know how to handle that).

If it is not possible to add the same control instance to multiple containers, is there a better way to accomplish the task than raising and subscribing to events?

Comment: You cannot add one control to multiple containers.

Comment: You cant, you can only notify your friends to also change..

Comment: Why the downvote? This is my first time posting a question, and I would like to know how to do better next time.

Comment: I think the question is quite ok, maybe paste some code of the solution that works, but you don't like it, so we could hint how to make it better and a snippet showing how you are trying to add same control to multiple containers and what errors are shown

Comment: No.  A control can have only 1 Parent.    A workaround would be: Move the control from 1 page to the next on the VisibleChanged event of each page.  From the user's view, the control exists on every page, but really it is being moved to the 'current' page as it becomes visible.

Comment: @David, thanks. Your workaround is the perfect solution in my case. If you want to make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you are wanting, controls can only have 1 Parent.

A workaround would be: Move the control from one page to the next on the VisibleChanged event of each page. From the user's view, the control exists on every page, but really it is being moved to the 'current' page as it becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, extend `ToolStripDropDownButton` with some data object, then create multiple instances of `ToolStripDropDownButton` it with different parents, then connect them to the same data object, and use the data object to keep `ToolStripDropDownButton` instances synchronized, for example like this:

```
public class MyToolStripDropDownButton : ToolStripDropDownButton
{
    public MyData Data { get; private set; }
    public MyToolStripDropDownButton():base()
    {
        this.Text = "Options";
    }

    public void Initialize(MyData data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Data.ElementsToNotify.Add(this);
        foreach (string option in this.Data.Options.Keys)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem(option);
            item.CheckOnClick = true;
            item.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(item_CheckedChanged);
            this.DropDownItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    void item_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem item = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        this.Data.OnSelectOption(item.Text, item.Checked);
    }

}

public class MyData
{
    public List<MyToolStripDropDownButton> ElementsToNotify { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Options { get; private set; }

    public MyData()
    {
        this.Options = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        this.ElementsToNotify = new List<MyToolStripDropDownButton>();
    }

    public void OnSelectOption(string option, bool isChecked)
    {
        Options[option]=isChecked;

        foreach (MyToolStripDropDownButton btn in ElementsToNotify)
        {
            foreach(ToolStripMenuItem  item in btn.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
            {
                item.Checked = Options[item.Text];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

// .......................

```
        MyData data = new MyData();
        data.Options.Add("A", false);
        data.Options.Add("B", false);
        data.Options.Add("C", false);

        MyToolStripDropDownButton mb1 = new MyToolStripDropDownButton();
        mb1.Initialize(data);

        MyToolStripDropDownButton mb2 = new MyToolStripDropDownButton();
        mb2.Initialize(data);

        toolStrip1.Items.Add(mb1);
        toolStrip2.Items.Add(mb2);
```